# How get windowsApps folder (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps) permissions in wpf?

Tags: c#, permissions

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps

I've used WPF Core and my app needs to access to the above folder. Can I get this permissions in c# or not?

Comment: Why don't you use one of the folders the program has access to by default?

Comment: all of my folders in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps here . because its appx

Comment: Yes, but windows, and other OS-ses, have designated folders for applications to store data, user or application specific. You should have a look at them and try them before messing with the default permission structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
Debug.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData));
```